# Canvas drawImage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, canvas

I need to change the background colour to match the video colour in Wordpress row.
It works in firefox\edge\safari
But doesn't work in chrome. It returns RGB (0,0,0)

page with issue - http://flex.tmweb.ru

```
window.onload = function() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('video-15-1_html5');
    var row = document.getElementById('globe-video');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    var p = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + p[0] + "," + p[1] + "," + p[2] + ")";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there's some kind of timing issue, where Chrome is differing from the other browsers in terms of when it calls onload vs. when the video itself has loaded anything.

Try checking to see if the video has loaded before doing your canvas thing, and then waiting if necessary:

```
function onVideoLoaded() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('video-15-1_html5');
    var row = document.getElementById('globe-video');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    var p = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + p[0] + "," + p[1] + "," + p[2] + ")";
}

window.onload = function() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('video-15-1_html5');

    if (vid.readyState === 4) {
        onVideoLoaded();
    } else {
        vid.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
            if (vid.readyState === 4) {
                onVideoLoaded();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

See this MDN documentation on `HTMLMediaElement.readyState`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Comment: Thank you, this is the right advice. Found problem, the video does not play at all in chrome

Comment: Ah, that would do it! :)

Comment: Now the problem with Edge. It does not enter to the onVideoLoaded function.

Comment: I had a typo in my code which I corrected, could be related if you used my code? (had "obj" instead of "vid") It is fixed now. Otherwise not sure why Edge would have issues.

Comment: Yes, I saw your typo.  The problem is that the Edge never readyState === 4. Apparently, I will have to write an exception for it, not the most beautiful solution.